# Convert date in bash back to iso

Tags: bash, date

We create a date format like that:`releaseVersion=$(date +%y%m%d%H%M)`
The result is `2105231450`
How can I convert it back to iso format?
I'm trying `date -d '2105031452' +'%y%m%d%H%M'` but getting `date: invalid date ‘2105031452’`
The final format should be `2021-05-23 14:50`
How can I do that?

Comment: Don't convert it to that format in the first place. Isn't that an option?

Comment: You'll want to read about [the valid `date` input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats)

Comment: Store the date in an neutral, intermediate format, like `%s`, that `date` can use for input. Then use *that* to produce both the release version and the ISO timestamp.

Comment: Pedantically, that's not strictly ISO datetime format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations -- "Separating date and time parts with [characters other than "T"] such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601,"

Comment: @oguzismail I copied two lines from our code it is not one after the other so, no we cannot  just "dont convert it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is bash, another option is using the *parameter expansion* for substring indexes, e.g.

```sh
r=2105231450; isodate="20${r:0:2}-${r:2:2}-${r:4:2} ${r:6:2}:${r:8:2}:00"
```

Then:

```
$ date -d "$isodate"
Sun May 23 14:50:00 CDT 2021
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the year occurs in this century, I'd use string manipulation:

```sh
$ echo '2105231450' | sed -E 's/(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/20\1-\2-\3 \4:\5/'
2021-05-23 14:50
```

Comment: That's a good back-reference workout `:)` I like it.

Comment: works gr8! both answered are good (also @David), but I can choose only one :-)

Comment: No worries, the key is that you now know several different approaches you can take to separate the values. As I wrote, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS,

```
$ date -j -f %y%m%d%H%M 2105311209  +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M
2021-05-31 12:09
```

Note that -f is used to specify the input format.

Comment: sounds gr8, but I'm not using mack, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ time=2105231450
$ date -d "${time:0:6} ${time:6:4}"
Sun 23 May 14:50:00 CEST 2021
$ date -d "${time:0:6} ${time:6:4}" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
2021-05-23 14:50
```

Comment: `${time:6:8}` shouldn't be a problem but `${time:6:4}` is more accurate.

Comment: @Darkman thanks, of course there should be a proper `length`. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A date is a string, possibly empty, containing many items separated by whitespace. The whitespace may be omitted when no ambiguity arises.

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html#General-date-syntax

d0="2105031452"; date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" -d "${d0:0:6} ${d0:7}"